# Mypy seems to ignore bound of a TypeVar type

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

For example, I have a piece of code like the following:

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar, cast

class SuperClass:
    pass


T = TypeVar('T', bound=SuperClass)


def cast_to(obj: SuperClass, cast_to: Type[T] = SuperClass) -> T:
    return cast(cast_to, obj)
```

And I saved it in `type_check.py`. If I run mypy on it, I got the following error messages:

```
type_check.py:10: error: Incompatible default for argument "cast_to" (default has type "Type[SuperClass]", argument has type "Type[T]")
type_check.py:11: error: Invalid type "cast_to"
```

From my understanding of `bound` in `TypeVar`, as long as a `T` is a subclass of `SuperClass`, it should be fine. But then why mypy is throwing out error here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code: first the signature of your `cast_to` function should be:

```
def cast_to(obj: SuperClass, cast_to: Type[T] = Type[SuperClass]) -> T:
```

Then, in your `cast` statement, I'm not sure `mypy` will allow you to use `cast_to` as a first argument of `cast`. Instead you can try:

```
def cast_to(obj: SuperClass, cast_to: Type[T]) -> T:
    return cast(T, obj)
```

Of course, with this definition you won't be able to call `cast_to` with only one argument.

---

I'm now going to ask: why do you feel you need to do this? are you sure your design is good? `cast` should be used in very particular cases; the documentation states:

> Casts are used to silence spurious type checker warnings and give the type checker a little help when it can’t quite understand what is going on.

So you should seriously question your design here! give us a little more information about what you're trying to achieve. Maybe there are better and cleaner designs than what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Basically, I'm trying to build a deserialization function that can automatically cast the loaded object to the specified type, and I want to restrict the type to be the subtype of `SuperClass`.

Comment: @NoSegfault Right, that's what I understood from your code. But why do you need to do this? where are your objects coming from? can't mypy keep track of their types? (and if not, why? what in your design makes mypy lose track of the object's types?).

Comment: The object comes from a loaded pickle, and it could be any subclass of `SuperClass`. And actually, in my code, `cast_to` function instead of taking an object, it takes a path to the pickle file, and the function is named as `load`. The return type of `load` is `SuperClass` even though it's actually a subclass of `SuperClass`. This is problematic when I'm using the object as the type checker will complain some method is not defined in `SuperClass`. Initially, I did a typecast every time there's an object loaded, which is annoying. So I just fused cast into the load function.

Comment: @NoSegfault Ok, it makes sense then!

Comment: Thanks for the help!